# Ionic Pinch to Zoom

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm doing a mobile app using npm, Ionic Framework & Angularjs, I have a module in my app where an image needs to be zoom. I got stuck here for 2days already, I already tried using Hammer.js and ion-scroll, and $ionicGesture, the problem is that, in Hammer.js pinch doesn't work, but all other gestures work. So I tried using $ionicGesture but it doesn't have a pinch.  I just wanna ask, what is the equivalent property of pinch under $ionicGesture directive?

```
$scope.myGesture = function(){
    alert("event triggered");
}
```

on my html: i have `<div on-tap="myGesture()">`

Yes it's working but I want to have a pinch action to zoom the image? Is there any other way to make an image zoom other than these things I tried?

Comment: did you solve it !

Comment: yep but I didn't used $ionicGestures though

Comment: How did you solve it? Please upload the solution. I'm also facing the same issue.